# Launcher wont open my JFrame

Tags: java, class, methods, window, jframe

I'm trying to open one of my classes that involve a JFrame using a simple launcher:

```
public class Launcher {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new StartScreen();

   }

}
```

This launcher is meant to launch the class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class StartScreen extends JFrame {
private static JFrame frame;
GameKeyboard GK;

boolean gamePlay = false;
boolean gameQuit = false;
boolean gameTwoPlayer = false;
String option;

//set dimension of window and buttons
public final int screenWidth = 800; // Width of window
public final int screenHeight = screenWidth / 12 * 9; // Height of window

private static Graphics gr;

//store images
private static Image background;
private static Image play;
private static Image twoPlayer;
private static Image quit;
private static Image playSelected;
private static Image twoPlayerSelected;
private static Image quitSelected;

public void StartScreen() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    setSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
    frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //         frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setTitle("Space Wars Menu");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    BufferedImage canvas=new BufferedImage(920,720,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    gr=canvas.getGraphics();

    JLabel label=new JLabel(new ImageIcon(canvas));
    frame.add(label);

    MenuKeyboard.initialise();

    //load images
    background = GameImage.loadImage("Images//background.jpg");
    play = GameImage.loadImage("Images//play.png");
    playSelected = GameImage.loadImage("Images//playSelected.png");
    twoPlayer = GameImage.loadImage("Images//twoPlayer.png");
    twoPlayerSelected = GameImage.loadImage("Images//twoPlayerSelected.png");
    quit = GameImage.loadImage("Images//quit.png");
    quitSelected = GameImage.loadImage("Images//quit.png");


    //draw images
    gr.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
    gr.drawImage(playSelected, 160, -50, null);
    gr.drawImage(twoPlayer, 160, 150, null);
    gr.drawImage(quit, 160, 250, null);

    int specialKey = MenuKeyboard.getSpecialKey();
    while(gamePlay == false)
    {

        if (MenuKeyboard.getSpecialKey() == 40) //if down pressed
        {
            gr.drawImage(twoPlayerSelected, 160, 150, null);
            gr.drawImage(play, 160, -50, null);
          }

      }

   }
}
```

The class is not finished yet obviously but I was just testing if it would open up a window and load all the images, but no window even gets opened.. despite the classes actually being linked. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor is in reality a method with a constructor name.

You should switch from this:

```
public void StartScreen() {
    // Code
}
```

to this:

```
public StartScreen() {
    // Code
}
```

Comment: Tried that but then it expects return type when compiling the startscreen class and I dont know how to go about that

Comment: The compiler cannot expect a return type from a constructor. What compilation error are you getting exactly?

Comment: "Invalid method declaration: return type required" and it's suggesting I use void if I don't want to return any values (which is why I used it)

Comment: I'm having no problem with the modification on my local machine with your code. Can you try creating an empty class with only a constructor to see how the compiler reacts?

Comment: public class constructor
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int result;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class constructor
     */
    public constructor()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        x = 30;
        y = 5;
        
        result = x*y;
        
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}

just made that in the same project folder and it worked fine..

Comment: Also just linked Launcher class to the constructor one and that worked fine too

Comment: I've seemed to fix it by just changing the class and constructor name from StartScreen to MenuScreen ahahah wut

Comment: I was about to propose you to try putting everything in a brand new StartScreen class template, but I'm glad a refactoring did the trick! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop runs continuously which is stepping on the Swing event thread effectively freezing it and preventing Swing from drawing anything. Solution: get rid of that while loop.

Instead use Key Bindings to trap specific key presses. If you need a game loop, use a Swing Timer.

Tutorials:

- [Overall Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)
- [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)
- [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

---

**Edit**

Your StartScreen class has no constructor. Get rid of the *void* return type in your pseudo constructor.

Other issues:

- You should not use null layouts.
- Most of your variables should not be static.

Comment: Just commented out that whole loop and still the same problem occurs, no window is opened when I use the launcher.

Comment: Tried that but then it expects return type when compiling the startscreen class and I dont know how to go about that

Comment: @user1840051: then you need to post the complete error message and your code attempt. You've got some significant other problems with that code, but fortunately all are fixable.

Comment: "Invalid method declaration: return type required" and yeah my code is all over the place, I'm still new to Java, thank you for the tutorial links though I'll be sure to take a look :)

Comment: @user1840051: is this your complete StartScreen class? Do you have another constructor anywhere else? Are you misspelling or miscapitalizaing anything? Something is definitely amiss.

Comment: No that is literally the whole class copy n pasted and I've been checking for misselling and all that stuff for a good while now and cant find anything. I have other classes in my project but the only ones linked to StartScreen are the launcher and GameImage and KeyboardListener. I'm just as confused as you :(

Comment: I've seemed to fix it by just changing the class and constructor name from StartScreen to MenuScreen, weird aha! thanks anyway